# Validate form without reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello guys i'm french beginner so i apologize for my school english :)

I have one form with two select, one for my buildings types and one for the citys. I need to validate this form without reload the page and show directly the result of selected values under my form.

I work on Wordpress.

Archive.php:

```
<form  id="filtreform">
    <select class="menufiltre" name="type">
        ?php
        while ($row = $resultat->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<option class='filtre' value='".$row['meta_value']."'>".$row['meta_value']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <select class="menufiltre" name="city">
        <?php
        while ($row = $resultat2->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<option class='filtre' value='".$row['meta_value']."'>".$row['meta_value']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <button class="menufiltrebutton">Valider</button>
    <span class='filtre'><a href='../biens-immobiliers'>Tous</a></span>
</form>
```

On my functions.php file added two jquery scripts and one for ajax script.
functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery' );
function jquery(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.validate.min', ("/wp-content/themes/restinn/js/jquery.validate.min.js"));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', ("/wp-content/themes/restinn/js/jquery.min.js"));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax' );
function ajax(){
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax', ("/wp-content/themes/restinn/js/ajax.js"));
}
```

On my ajax.js file i added some code to test if my form works or not. And it's doesn't work i don't know why :/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.menufiltrebutton').click(function() {
        alert('YOLO1');
        jQuery('.menufiltre').change();
        $(this).css("background-color", "#D6D6FF");
    a    lert('YOLO2');
});
```

i use this doc to help me: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_change_trigger

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Look for jquery `.on('submit')`

Comment: That's ok i solved my problem thx :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.on('submit') will trigger the next function to fire.